# Perl save print as variable

Tags: perl

I have a command

```
print $_->{href} . "\n" for $mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i);
```

that prints out the exact link I would like to save as a variable.  Although when I try to do

```
my $link = $_->{href} . "\n" for $mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i);
```

it does not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `$mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i)` returns exactly one element, then you can write:

```
my $link = [$mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i)]->[0]->{href} . "\n";
```

If it can return multiple elements — or zero elements — then maybe you mean this:

```
my $link;
$link .= $_->{href} . "\n" for $mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i);
```

Comment: Thanks thats the help I needed!

Comment: Or `join( "\n", map { $->{href} } $mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i))`

Comment: @Axeman: I'm sure you're aware of this, but other readers' benefit -- your version differs slightly from mine, in that it doesn't include a final `"\n"`. I don't know if that's a good change or a bad one. :-P

Comment: @ruakh, Just add the `, ''` before the last paren, then. Or you could even do this: `join( '', map { $->{href} . "\n" } $mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i))`

Comment: @Axeman: The first of those differs from mine in that it includes a `"\n"` even if the function returns no results; I doubt that's a good change. But yeah, the second one is equivalent to mine.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code snippet is equivalent to:

```
for $_ ($mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i)) {
    print $_->{href} . "\n"
}
```

The second is equivalent to:

```
for $_ ($mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i)) {
    my $link = $_->{href} . "\n";
}
```

So, the `$link` variable is local to the `for` block, and is not visible outside of that block. It will work if you first declare the variable outside of the block:

```
my $link;

for $_ ($mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i)) {
    $link = $_->{href} . "\n";
}
```

Or, using the short form as in your code:

```
my $link;

$link = $_->{href} . "\n" for $mech->find_link_dom(text_regex => qr/pdf/i);
```